# MOD_Rewrite directive to implement a catchall redirection

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my website, there are three to four types of URLS (each can have different parameters to represent different pages). They are like `http://foo.com/users/username`, `http://foo.com/questions/question_text`, `http://foo.com/new_question`, etc.

I use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite the URL coming from client-side, i.e `http://foo.com/users/username` becomes `http://foo.com/users?username=username`, then this request goes to `http://foo.com/users`, which does the rest.

Now I want that, barring these 3-4 pre-defined templates, if any other request comes, like `http://foo.com/abracadabra`, the user should be redirected to the home page `http://foo.com/`. Is there any such directive that can implement this catchall redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long way would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the request isn't actually a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request isn't actually a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request isn't specifically for favicon.ico (though the first 
# RewriteCond should take care of this, it's in the first .htaccess file
# I grabbed to verify)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# Change the request from whatever the user entered to "/"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /
```

But you really shouldn't do this.  It's much friendlier if you actually serve a 404 error and a custom error page if the requested page doesn't exist.  Also, if you do this and your site has to go through a third-party security scan, you're going to generate a ton of false-positive security holes for the report.

Comment: Well, that is a mouthful! Can you please explain what you just wrote, I can't discern an iota of it.

Comment: Thanks. By `REQUEST_FILENAME`, did you mean the base PHP files I mentioned, like `users`, `questions`, etc? And again, can you please elaborate you last **false-positive** bit ? (Please don't be annoyed!)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond - `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the full path to the requested file.  The part about false-positives only applies if your site will have to go through any security auditing (to make it PCI compliant, for example).  If you're not familiar with that, then it doesn't apply to you.